# How to copy a git repo with dependencies that are specific to that environment

Tags: git, laravel

I use a Mac at home and Windows at work.

I am working on Laravel project at home and pushed it to GitLab. I haven't adjusted any of the `.gitignore` files so when I copied the repo there were numerous dependencies and environment settings for the project that didn't push to GitLab.

So then I thought I would override the `.gitignore` files and add everything. This included all the dependencies and the env settings, but when I go to run it at work, it resulted in errors looking for dependencies specific to Mac.

So I guess I am trying to figure out how one typically clones a repo from computer to computer. The two methods I tried didn't really work.

Does one install the dependencies for the project first, in the case of Laravel `laravel new [use the same name for the project]` on the Windows computer? Or do you download the repo and then install the dependencies by rebuilding them probably with some command to reinstall dependencies?

Comment: did you try `composer install` or `composer update` ?

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried that as I am trying to figure out how to solve the problem. I will give that a shot. It will install the dependencies for the project? Or just Composer and Laravel? Those are installed on both computers already. It is just the project dependencies.

Comment: What OS-specific things is it looking for? Just stuff in the `vendor` folder, or something else?

Comment: I've posted an answer. This the the right way to go.

Comment: @ScottWeldon Yes, primarily stuff in the `vendor` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make it work,

Do these steps.

1. Run `composer install` or `composer update` on both systems.
2. Modify `.env` files as per your database username and password defined.
3. If you've some node dependencies then run `npm update`.
4. If you're using gulp then don't forget to run `gulp`.

Don't modify anything apart from `.env` file to make it work on both the systems.

Feel free to comment if you face any kind of error. I've been using more than 2 places to code and continue development so yeah, this is the way.
Hope this helps. :)